# Rails 4 Add Parameters to New Record Creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, controller, strong-parameters

I am having trouble getting a parameter to show up as an additional param when I create a new item.

Conceptually I have 3 models, Tickets, Issues and a join table IssueTickets.

Tickets have many issues through IssueTickets
Issues have many tickets through IssueTickets

A user can create a ticket from an issue.  When they click the new ticket button i'm trying to get the id of it to go through so that I can associate it in the join table and do some custom alerting.

```
 issues/show.html.erb
<%= link_to "Create Ticket", new_ticket_path(:issues => @issue.id), :class => 'btn' %>
```

The ID shows up in the URI, however i don't have access to it when the request goes through.  I suspect that it is related to strong parameters in my ticket controller.

```
def ticket_params
  params.require(:ticket).permit(:title, :description, :status, :priority, :latitude, :longitude, :issues)
  params.permit(:issues)
end
```

So, what am i doing wrong, and is their a better way to do this?  I was thinking accepts nested parameters, but all i am doing is creating the association between the ticket and issue and then alerting the associated users (both the issue owner and the dispatcher of the tickets)

Answer (score 0):

Alright so was making a silly mistake, hope this helps someone else in the future.

I was permitting this in the strong parameters but wasn't assigning anything in the new action.  After handling the parameter in the new action so that the create action saw it everything worked just fine.